# Small game in Kotlin - counting score problem

Tags: class, kotlin, counting

I have an excersise to create a dog and a cat class. Each of these classes should contain the same fields (weight, speed, voice, strength). Then write a function that will return the winner of the duel - it gives one point for the animal who has greater value of the specific field (eg. cat.weigh > dog.weigh -> cat has 1 point). The animal with the highest number of points wins.
Also I wanted it to be possible to enter the specific values in a console by the user.

The function recognises correctly who should win - eg. the user enters "20" for all dog's values, and "10" for cat's so the function prints "Dog Doge has 1 points and wins!", but as you can see, the function counts the points wrong (dog should have 4 points, not 1).

The whole code:

```
open class Cat(name: String)
{
    var name = name
    var weight = 1
    var speed = 1
    var voice = 1
    var strength = 1
}
class Dog(name: String) : Cat(name)
{}

fun whoWins(dog1: Dog, cat1: Cat)
{
    var scoreCat = 0
    var scoreDog = 0

    if (dog1.strength == cat1.strength)
    { scoreDog =+ 0; scoreCat =+ 0}
    else if (dog1.strength > cat1.strength)
    { scoreDog =+ 1; scoreCat=+ 0}
    else { scoreDog=+ 0; scoreCat =+ 1}

    if (dog1.speed == cat1.speed)
    { scoreDog =+ 0; scoreCat =+ 0}
    else if (dog1.speed > cat1.speed)
    { scoreDog =+ 1; scoreCat=+ 0}
    else { scoreDog=+ 0; scoreCat =+ 1}

    if (dog1.weight == cat1.weight)
    { scoreDog =+ 0; scoreCat =+ 0}
    else if (dog1.weight > cat1.weight)
    { scoreDog =+ 1; scoreCat=+ 0}
    else { scoreDog=+ 0; scoreCat =+ 1}

    if (dog1.voice == cat1.voice)
    { scoreDog =+ 0; scoreCat =+ 0}
    else if (dog1.voice > cat1.voice)
    { scoreDog =+ 1; scoreCat=+ 0}
    else { scoreDog=+ 0; scoreCat =+ 1}

    if (scoreCat == scoreDog)
    { println("Draw! Cat ${cat1.name} and dog ${dog1.name} has the same score!")}
    else if (scoreCat > scoreDog)
    { println("Cat ${cat1.name} has $scoreCat points and wins!")}
    else
    { println("Dog ${dog1.name} has $scoreDog points and wins!")}
}
fun main()
{

    var Doge= Dog("Doge")
    var Felix = Cat("Felix")

    println("Enter ${Doge.name}’s weight:")
    Doge.weight = readLine()!!.toInt()
    println("Enter ${Doge.name}’s speed:")
    Doge.speed = readLine()!!.toInt()
    println("Enter ${Doge.name}’s voice strength:")
    Doge.voice= readLine()!!.toInt()
    println("Enter ${Doge.name}’s strength:")
    Doge.strength = readLine()!!.toInt()

    println("Enter ${Felix.name}’s weight:")
    Felix.weight = readLine()!!.toInt()
    println("Enter ${Felix.name}’s speed:")
    Felix.speed = readLine()!!.toInt()
    println("Enter ${Felix.name}’s voice strength:")
    Felix.voice = readLine()!!.toInt()
    println("Enter ${Felix.name}’s strength:")
    Felix.strength = readLine()!!.toInt()

    whoWins(Doge, Felix)
}
```

Comment: Your code says that a Dog is a type of Cat…!  Code doesn't _have_ to match reality exactly, but places where it doesn't are more likely to lead to confusion and bugs.  (The usual approach to this sort of case is to have a base class, perhaps called Animal or Mammal or whatever, with the relevant fields, and then have both Cat and Dog extend _that_.)

Comment: **Tip:** In this case, It's better to use `when` instead of `if` where there are more than 2 conditions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct way of adding to and updating the value of a variable is to use the plusAssign operator `+=`.
You are using the reverse `=+` which effectively means you are assigning the value of positive 1 every time.

You can read more about the syntax here.
https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/operator-overloading.html#assignments

Comment: Just to be clear, ``+=`` is an operator - ``a += b`` adds the value of ``b`` to the value of ``a``, and then assigns the result to ``a``. ``=+`` **isn't** an operator, and ``a =+ b`` is basically ``a = +b`` with different spacing, i.e. "set ``a`` to the value of ``b``" (the ``+`` is redundant)

Answer (score 1):

You can simplify your code by using the `++` to increment the value. Also, you don't need to specify that a value increases by 0, just don't modify it.

```
fun whoWins(dog1: Dog, cat1: Cat)
{
    var scoreCat = 0
    var scoreDog = 0

    if (dog1.strength > cat1.strength)
    { scoreDog++ }
    else {scoreCat++}

    if (dog1.speed > cat1.speed)
    { scoreDog++}
    else {scoreCat++}


    if (dog1.weight > cat1.weight)
    { scoreDog++}
    else { scoreCat++}
  

     if (dog1.voice > cat1.voice)
    { scoreDog++}
    else { scoreCat++}


    if (scoreCat == scoreDog)
    { println("Draw! Cat ${cat1.name} and dog ${dog1.name} has the same score!")}
    else if (scoreCat > scoreDog)
    { println("Cat ${cat1.name} has $scoreCat points and wins!")}
    else
    { println("Dog ${dog1.name} has $scoreDog points and wins!")}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Rishabh Kohli answer is correct, but I would also make some improvement to your code to avoid code replication:

1. Define a class `Animal` with immutable val properties, adding a `AnimalType`. No need to define two identical classes with same properties.

```kotlin
class Animal(
   val name: String,
   val weight: Int,
   val speed: Int,
   val voice: Int,
   val strength: Int,
   val type: AnimalType
)

enum class AnimalType {
        DOG, CAT
}
```

2. Refactor your "whoWins" function to return the winner with its score:

```kotlin
fun whoWins(dog: Animal, cat: Animal): Pair<Animal?, Int?> {
        var catScore = 0
        var dogScore = 0

        when {
            dog.strength > cat.strength -> dogScore++
            dog.strength < cat.strength -> catScore++
        }

        when {
            dog.speed > cat.speed -> dogScore++
            dog.speed < cat.speed -> catScore++
        }

        when {
            dog.weight > cat.weight -> dogScore++
            dog.weight < cat.weight -> catScore++
        }

        when {
            dog.voice > cat.voice -> dogScore++
            dog.voice < cat.voice -> catScore++
        }

        return when {
            catScore < dogScore -> Pair(dog, dogScore)
            catScore > dogScore -> Pair(cat, catScore)
            else -> Pair(null, catScore)
        }
    }
```

3. Simplify your main by using run function on the returned winner:

```kotlin
fun main() {
        val doge = Animal("Doge", 20, 10, 25, 50, AnimalType.DOG)
        val felix = Animal("Felix", 10, 50, 15, 10, AnimalType.CAT)
        val fight = whoWins(doge, felix)

        fight.first?.run {
            println("${this.type} ${this.name} has ${fight.second} points and wins!")
        } ?: kotlin.run {
            println("Animals have the same score: ${fight.second}!")
        }
    }
```